# Copy text to the clipboard from the OS/X terminal

Tags: macos, shell, iterm

I am often having to copy and paste text from the terminal. Is there a way to redirect the output of a command into a shell variable or another command that would place the output in the clipboard?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.  Anything sent to `pbcopy` goes into the clipboard.  Running `pbpaste` sends the contents of the clipboard to standard output and you can chain them just like all other commands.

You can find some example uses here:  http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/05/manipulating-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 4):

`pbcopy` and `pbpaste` replace non-ASCII characters with question marks in some environments. It can be avoided by setting `LC_CTYPE` to `UTF-8`.

```
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 pbpaste
```

You could also use osascript:

```
osascript -e 'on run {input}
set the clipboard to input
end' "ä"

osascript -e 'the clipboard as text'
```